# How do I get rid of these empty strings?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

My constructor takes a filename of a text file and converts it to an `ArrayList` of all the words in lowercase, without punctuation or white space. These specs, along with the constructor's argument are specified by my homework assignment, so don't suggest I change them.

```java
private ArrayList<String> list;

public Tokenizer(String file) throws IOException {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    String thisLine;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(thisLine.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+"," ").toLowerCase().split("\\s+")));
}
```

My problem is that there are many empty strings that appear. I've tried using "-1" as the second argument in "split", but it doesn't seem to do anything.

My other question is if its inefficient to do `Arrays.asList`, or if I should just create an iterator, plus if you think I do anything else wrong. eg, is there another way to input a filename into the `BufferedReader`?

Thanks

Edit 1:

Below is test I used for an online book (it is a text file and there are not problems with the text file) I found on project Gutenberg. I also get similar results when using a text file that I personally create, so don't think its a problem with the text file itself.

In fact, I'll just reproduce my entire code since its pretty simple:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Tokenizer {
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public Tokenizer(String file) throws IOException {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        String thisLine;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(thisLine.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+"," ").toLowerCase().trim().split("\\s+")));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> wordList() {
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Tokenizer T = new Tokenizer("C:\\...\\1898amongmyb00loweuoft_djvu.txt");

        ArrayList<String> array = T.wordList();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(array.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my output:

```
i
9



digitized
by
the
internet
archive

in
2007
with
funding
from

microsoft
corporation
```

No, those empty lines are not white space. They are empty strings. As in, "". I hope I am as clear as possible.

Since it will probably cause confusion, no that is not the actual argument I use for the path name of the file. The ellipsis (the "...") is just a shorthand, so I don't have to reveal my computer directories to the internet.

Also, yes there is another empty string at the end, but this website's interface will not let me put it there.

Edit 2:

I always forget something, here is the first few lines of the text file:

I 9

Digitized by the Internet Archive

in 2007 with funding from

Microsoft Corporation

http://www.archive.org/details/1898amongmyb00loweuoft

James Ettsscll Lotocll.

COMPLETE POETICAL AND PROSE WORKS. Riverside 
Edition, n vols, crown 8vo, gilt top, each, $ 1.50 ; the set, 
$ 1 6. 50.

1-4. Literary Essays (including My Study Windows, Among 
My Books, Fireside Travels) ; 5. Political Essays ; 6. Literary 
and Political Addresses ; 7. Latest Literary Essays and Ad- 
dresses, The Old English Dramatists ; 8-1 1. Poems.

PROSE WORKS. Riverside Edition. With Portraits. 7 vols, 
crown 8vo, gilt top, $10.50.

POEMS. Riverside Edition. With Portraits. 4 vols, crown 
8vo, gilt top, $6.00.

COMPLETE POETICAL WORKS. Cambridge Edition. 
Printed from clear type on opaque paper, and attractively 
bound. With a Portrait and engraved Title-page, and a 
Vignette of Lowell's Home, Elmwood. Large crown 8vo, $2.00. 
Household Edition. With Portrait and Illustrations. Crown 
8vo, $1.50.

Cabinet Edition. i8

I think I now see the problem. The empty strings correspond to the empty lines.

Edit 3:

So I ended up answering my own problem. I ended up doing this:

```
while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(thisLine.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+"," ").toLowerCase().split("\\s+")));
        while(newList.remove(""));     
        list.addAll(newList);
    }
```

I did try using an if statement, but then you are comparing the line before the split. This could be problematic because the split may produce some empty lines you would then miss. Therefore, I made the list I was going to add to my main list, but before adding it, I just went through it and deleted all of the instances of empty strings.

I don't really know if this is the most efficient way of doing things... if its not let me know!

Comment: Empty strings as in filled with ' ' whitespace? You can trim() that and if the length is 0 then it's a fully empty string.

Comment: by empty string, I mean "". By my understanding, this is what is normally meant by empty string. A string with nothing inside. Jeez, I didn't think it would cause confusion.

Comment: `thisLine.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+"," ")` This does not produce an empty string EVER unless `thisLine` is an empty string to begin with. Hence why the question was asked.

Comment: Something that might help is if you gave a sample sentence that is causing problems and ALSO gave us the list output so that we could see where the empty strings are being put in for whatever reason.

Comment: @Compass, the thing producing the empty strings is split. I know this for various reasons, including the fact that i've tested it. The replaceAll doesn't give any trouble.

Comment: @KeithEnlow, I'll add the test I used and the console output

Comment: You still didn't put the actual line before it was turned into a list. So we can see the actual punctuation and all before and after...

Comment: @Hank I think you answered your own question there at the end. Did it work?

Comment: Yep, I will post what I did. Don't know if its the best way to do it though

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most likely is that there is a space at the beginning or end of your `thisLine` read from the file. Which is very common for a text document to have lines like this. So if you call split on `\s+` and the line ends with a space, the very last thing will be an empty string.

To fix this, I would suggest to add a trim on your string before you do the split.

Using your code change it to:

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(thisLine.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+"," ").toLowerCase().trim().split("\\s+")));
```

Try that and see if it doesn't get rid of most if not all of your empty strings. Also, you should consider breaking this statement up into multiple operations so that it is easier to read.

Comment: So I tried this, but I still get the empty strings. I don't know if you thought this, but the empty strings appear in the middle of the list, not the at the ends. Why they appear is not apparent to me.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing `while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(thisLine.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+"," ").toLowerCase().trim().split("\\s+")));`

with: `while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null )
        if (thisLine.length() > 0)
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(thisLine.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", " ").toLowerCase().trim().split("\\s+")));`

Comment: I had already tried something similar. The problem with this is that it's possible to get empty strings from "split", that would then be missed and added to the ArrayList.

Comment: If that the case, you will need to discard them once you are done the split